# Meteor: Call server-side method by client

Tags: javascript, meteor

I'm creating a new user with `Accounts.createUser()` on client side in a Admin-Frontend. This works, but after creating the user, there is a auto-login, which is very logic, as the input has be done on client side.
But I want to create new users by an admin-account on frontend.

So I thought about creating a server-method, calling from client. But that doesn't work:

**server.js**

```
Meteor.methods({
    'createUserByAdmin': function(){
        console.log("Hello world");
        // Create user here
    }
});
```

**client.js**

```
Template.users.events({
    'submit form': function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        Meteor.call('createUserByAdmin');
    }
});
```

Now I would expect by submiting the form there should be "Hello world" on the console. But I don't get anything.

Comment: Are you looking at the browser console or the server side terminal? The server side code console.log() prints to the terminal FYI (I know, I've made this mistake :) )

Comment: Oops... Don't know what to say :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to look at the server console.